# Autocorrelation in Elo ratings

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive, elo

FiveThirtyEight [uses the following formula](https://fivethirtyeight.com/methodology/how-our-nfl-predictions-work/) for their NFL Elo ratings:
$$
R_i^{k+1} = R_i^k + K \cdot M(z) \cdot A(x) \cdot (S_{ij} - \sigma(x))
$$
where $z$ is the game's margin of victory, $x=R_i^k - R_j^k$, and
$$
\begin{align*}
M(z) &= \ln (|z|+1) \\
A(x) &= \frac{2.2}{2.2-0.001(-1)^{S_{ij}} x} = \frac{1}{1-(-1)^{S_{ij}}\frac{x}{2200}} \\
S_{ij} &= \begin{cases} 1 & i \text{ wins} \\ 0 & i \text{ loses}\end{cases} \\
\sigma(x) &= \frac{1}{1+10^{-x/400}}
\end{align*}
$$
Let's ignore ties.

My question is the specific justification for the $A(x)$ term: **why this form**, and **why those numbers.**  (More than a layman's explanation, as found [elsewhere already](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168047/accounting-for-autocorrelation-in-margin-based-elo-ratings).)

**What I (think I) understand already:**

I understand that $A(x)$ is intended to maintain stationarity in the model.  (This, to my understanding is not the same as correcting autocorrelation, but perhaps I misunderstand what 538 is doing.)

Intuitively, we see the function is designed so that

- If Team $i$ is the favorite ($x>0$), a loss is upweighted ($A(x)>0$) and a win is downweighted ($A(x)<0$).
- If Team $i$ is the underdog ($x<0$), the opposite.

However, this leaves the questions: why achieve this in this way? And why use the denominator $d=2200$?

Statistically speaking, we want $\mathbb{E}[R_i^{k+1}] = R_i^k$, i.e. we shouldn't expect Team $i$'s rating to increase --- if we did, ["we should have rated them higher to begin with"](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/introducing-nfl-elo-ratings/).  I believe this issue arises because of the $M(z)$ term, because without it, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[R_k^{k+1}] &= \mathbb{E}[R_i^k] + \mathbb{E}[k(S_{ij}-\sigma(x))] \\
&= R_i^k + k(\mathbb{E}[S_{ij}] - \sigma(x)) \\
&= R_i^k 
\end{align*}
$$
which is fine, I guess.

With $M(z)$, we need
$$
\mathbb{E}[M(z)\cdot A(x) \cdot (S_{ij} - \sigma(x))] = 0
$$
which, computing expectation over all possible game outcomes as encoded in $z$, given $R_i^k$ and $R_j^k$, implies
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 M(z) A(x) (-\sigma(x)) \text{Pr}(z) \ dz + \int_0^{\infty} M(z) A(x) (1-\sigma(x)) \text{Pr}(z) \ dz = 0
$$
over some distribution for $z$.  Rearranging, we get
$$
\frac{A(x; i \text{ win})}{A(x; i \text{ lose})} = \frac{\sigma(x)}{1-\sigma(x)} \frac{\mathbb{E}[M(z)|i \text{ lose}]}{\mathbb{E}[M(z)|i \text{ wins}]}
$$
and we would want some $A(x)$ so this would hold for any $x$.

We should be able to interpolate some simple function for the expected $M(z)$'s, and then if we are satisfied with our functional form for $A(x)$, solve for the denominator $d$.

Does this analysis seem correct?

**Edit.**  I worked out the empirical $M(z)$'s, and found they are decently approximated by the linear functions:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[M(z)|i \text{ win}] &\approx \frac{x}{1000} + 2.2 \\
\mathbb{E}[M(z)|i \text{ lose}] &\approx -\frac{x}{1000} + 2.2
\end{align*}
$$
If the $\sigma/(1-\sigma)$ term weren't there, this would give $d=2200$, but since it *is* there, I'm not sure what gives.